# BigBlueButton Crashing after upgrading VM RAM

Tags: docker, nginx, ram, esxi, bigbluebutton

Recently I Installed BigBlueButton with 4core CPU and 4GB Ram. 
After one month I upgrade RAM to 8GB there was no problem 
After two months I needed to Upgrade it so I  Upgrade it to 12GB RAM but it's crashed and it didn't work so I recovered snapshot.

Has anyone ever had same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to make it fixed

The only way to fix this issue is to reinstall the BigBlueButton again:

wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v xenial-220 -s bbb.domain.ir -e info@domain.ir -g

Don't worry about your data, your data will NOT lose and database will stable